# try, except and finally in python

Tags: python, exception, try-catch-finally

```
def finding(a,b):

    try:
        result=a+b
        return result
    except TypeError:
        return "please type only num"
    finally:
        return "this line will get print at last"

print(finding (5, 2))
```

I'm getting the output from the `finally`,
but I'm not getting the output from the `try`.

Comment: I should also get output of "finally" With output of "try" (result=7)

Comment: Why do you expect that? Your function can only `return` once and the one in `finally` is overriding both of the others.

Comment: Tangentially, overriding the useful default exception to `return` (or print, or whatever) something useless is a pathological antipattern. Exceptions are useful and informative, at least compared to what you are replacing them with here.

Comment: @PatrickArtner yeah i remembered just now that return will return once not twice.. Im  new to python 

Comment: @tripleee thankyou for correcting my mistake.. Im new to python sometimes i get confused.. I just remembered that return  can used once .. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Change your last two returns to print statements:

```
def finding(a,b):

    try:
        result=a+b
        return result
    except TypeError:
        print("please type only num")
    finally:
        print("this line will get print at last")

print(finding (5, 2))
```

Comment: This will fix the immediate error, but now the function returns `None` when there's a problem, which still hides it from the calling code. (Also, interactive I/O makes the function less suitable for use from other functions.)

Comment: And, you didn't fix the syntax error (`def` instead of `Def`)

Comment: @tripleee thank you i will remember your explanation 